# Running t-test on individual ratings or on means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I ran a study where each participant rated 20 different foods. There were two conditions, so half the participants saw one set of foods and half saw another. I would like to compare these two conditions using a t-test.

When making this comparison, should I: 
A) Compare the individual ratings for foods for one group to the individual ratings for foods for the other group 
B) First take the mean score of each individual food, then compare the means of one group to the means of the other group

How should I go about deciding?

I've included a simplified example to make this more concrete. 
If I did (A), I would compare the 9 individual values from Group 1 to the 9 individual values from Group 2. If I did (B), I would compare the means from Group 1 (which all happen to be 2 in this example) to the means from Group 2 (which are all 6 in this example).

```
Group1-A  Group 1-B  Group 1-C  Group2-A  Group2-B  Group2-C
1         3          2          5         7         6
3         2          1          6         5         7
2         1          3          7         6         5
```

Please let me know if any of this is unclear.

Comment: So you had in total 40 different foods, divided in two groups, A and B? Then people were randomized to test either A, or B, but not both? If that is right, you can do independent groups t-test, between the two groups ... A better design would have been possible

Comment: My understanding is that Group 1 rated 20 foods under one condition (let's say the room had blue lighting) and Group 2 rated 20 different foods under another condition (let's say the room had red lighting). You have no means of separating the effect of the light from the effect of the different foods - what if Group 1 rated different desserts and Group 2 rated different types of tofu? A naive analysis might show that blue light makes things more delicious, even though the lighting is irrelevant.